# A Reminder type in asp.net for windows computers

Tags: c#, windows, popup

Basically i need the way to just have a popup schedule to open every morning when the user log in his computer. an application to install in his computer. I am not quite sure what to use? Any direction

Comment: this wouldnt be a web popup, it would be a windows application/service. remove asp.net from the title and tags

Comment: @RPM1984: Maybe he means to open the web browser, showing a web application with the schedule. I agree the scenario seems a little convoluted, but he is quite insistent it's a web app, both in the title and two tags...

Comment: well, what i meant by web is to use this feature in a website. Meaning when the user log in the website i pop up the reminder.
But I believe a console or windows application wil be more suitable

Answer (score 1):

The 2 ways I have done something similar to this using Visual Studio and .net language are:

1) creating a Windows Service

2) creating a Console Application that runs from the task scheduler as described by user 281693

IMO Console app + task scheduler is easiest. Windows Service requires a bit more setting up.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Windows Task Scheduler. Go to Windows Scheduler. Add a task and select to run it when user logs on.

Comment: I need to check what schedule for the user in the day before poping up the app. Only windows sheduler seems not to be enough. isn t it?

Comment: You said in your question "the user log in his computer". You can schedule your task to run when the user logs onto his computer. Open windows task scheduler and you can see the options to select "Run when the user logs onto the computer"

Comment: It s a way, but i think it s more than that.. Another ideA will be to create a sidegadget type connecting with webservice..cool hein?